# training model for different batch sizes in keras

Tags: python, loops, keras, model-fitting

I want to train my model for different batch sizes i.e: [64, 128]
I am doing it with for loop like below

```
   epoch=2 
   batch_sizes = [128,256] 
   for i in range(len(batch_sizes)):
     history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_sizes[i], epochs=epochs, 
          callbacks=[early_stopping, chk], validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

for above code my model produce following results:

```
    Epoch 1/2
    311/311 [==============================] - 157s 494ms/step - loss: 0.2318 - 
    f1: 0.0723 
    Epoch 2/2
    311/311 [==============================] - 152s 488ms/step - loss: 0.1402 - 
    f1: 0.4360 

    Epoch 1/2
    156/156 [==============================] - 137s 877ms/step - loss: 0.1197 - 
    f1: **0.5450** 
    Epoch 2/2
    156/156 [==============================] - 136s 871ms/step - loss: 0.1132 - 
    f1: 0.5756
```

it looks like the model continues training after completing training for batch size 64, i.e I want to get my model trained for the next batch from scratch, how can I do it kindly guide me.
p.s: what i have tried:

```
   epoch=2 
   batch_sizes = [128,256] 
   for i in range(len(batch_sizes)):
     history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_sizes[i], epochs=epochs, 
          callbacks=[early_stopping, chk], validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
   keras.backend.clear_session()
```

it also did not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to define a model, and you would need to call that before the subsequent `fit` calls. If your model is contained within `model`, the weights are updated during training, and they stay that way after the fit call. That is why you need to redefine the model. This can help you

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

X = np.random.rand(1000,5)
Y = np.random.rand(1000,1)

def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(64,input_shape=(X.shape[1],)))
    model.add(Dense(Y.shape[1]))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='Adam')
    return model

epoch=2
batch_sizes = [128,256]
for i in range(len(batch_sizes)):
    model = build_model()
    history = model.fit(X, Y, batch_sizes[i], epochs=epoch, verbose=2)
    model.save('Model_' + str(batch_sizes[i]) + '.h5')
```

Then, the output looks like:

```
Epoch 1/2
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.3164
Epoch 2/2
8/8 - 0s - loss: 0.1367
Epoch 1/2
4/4 - 0s - loss: 0.7221
Epoch 2/2
4/4 - 0s - loss: 0.4787
```